# How can I use reflection in Hazelcast for different nodes?

Tags: serialization, reflection, hazelcast

I am try to develop a Hazelcast Client. This client will connect a cluster and display objects' values in Collections. Problem is that client will not know classes in cluster. Can I create dynamically these classes and use in my Hazelcast Client? I tried Hazelcast serialization and reflection but I did  not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

First, plz have a look at the existing client implementations. Clients have been implemented in many programming languages, thus maybe you don't have to implement the client again.

Now, when it comes to your question: it is not a problem if you store primitive data types in your Collection, e.g. `String`, `Integer`, etc.

If you store custom classes, let them implement `Portable` or `IdentifiedDataSerializable`. It will enable creating the same data structures on the client side. Have a look at the C++ serialisation example:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#c-client-code-examples

Comment: I am developing for an open source project this with Java.Primitive data types and String are okay. I don't understand to serialize. My client will connect any cluster and dynamically find classes and create object. Is that possible? I guess, I have to use reflection, class loader and Hazelcast serializable but I didn't. How I can deserialize for non-existing classes?

Comment: what does it mean «dynamically find classes and create object»?